# Example of accessing Azure SQL Server using User Assigned Managed Entity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

This is a single tenant Active Directory scenario. I have created a User Assigned Managed Identity (UAMI) in a subscription A and and made it as owner of an Azure SQL Server resource which exists in subscription B. Now considering this, is there a PowerShell example template somewhere that can allow me to verify that I am able to access SQL Server using the UAMI. It could be something basic like listing databases or anything like that.